# System of inequalities. Points of intersection?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

$x^2+y^2<=81$

$y<x$

Is this correct?
My answer: (-9sqrt(2)/2,-9sqrt(2)/2), (9sqrt(2)/2,9sqrt(2)/2)

Comment: Systems of two inequalities in two variables produce a _region_ in the plane (provided the intersection is not the empty set), which needs to be graphed.  It won't be represented simply by intervals, as happens for an inequality with one variable.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

Notice $x^2 + y^2 \leq 81 = 9^2 $ is the set of all $(x,y)$ that lies inside a circle(centered at the origin) of radius $9$, and including its boundary.

and $y < x $ is the set of all points that lie below the the $45^0$ degrees line excluding the points in the diagonal.